# while i troubleshoot freeradius server, at ./radiusd.conf, i got an output like this

Tags: configuration, freeradius

When i run a file which is in usr/local/etc/raddb/radiusd.conf 
  can it create any problem??.
"./radiusd.conf" command, i got an error as shown as below:

```
./radiusd.conf: line 54: prefix: command not found
./radiusd.conf: line 55: exec_prefix: command not found
./radiusd.conf: line 56: sysconfdir: command not found
./radiusd.conf: line 57: localstatedir: command not found
./radiusd.conf: line 58: sbindir: command not found
./radiusd.conf: line 59: logdir: command not found
./radiusd.conf: line 60: raddbdir: command not found
./radiusd.conf: line 61: radacctdir: command not found
./radiusd.conf: line 65: name: command not found
./radiusd.conf: line 68: confdir: command not found
./radiusd.conf: line 69: run_dir: command not found
./radiusd.conf: line 72: db_dir: command not found  
./radiusd.conf: line 106: libdir: command not found
./radiusd.conf: line 117: pidfile: command not found
./radiusd.conf: line 219: max_request_time: command not found 
./radiusd.conf: line 238: cleanup_delay: command not found    
./radiusd.conf: line 257: max_requests: command not found
./radiusd.conf: line 273: listen: command not found
./radiusd.conf: line 287: type: =: not found
./radiusd.conf: line 287: type: auth: not found
./radiusd.conf: line 306: ipaddr: command not found
./radiusd.conf: line 316: port: command not found
./radiusd.conf: line 343: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
./radiusd.conf: line 343: `}'
```

please help me out of this , i stucked at this bug. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug, radiusd.conf isn't executable, it's meant to be read by the `radiusd` binary.